# Setup C11 in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, c11

In university we need a development environment for c11. Most of us are using CLion. I however have been trying to use vs code. Does anyone know how to do that?

I've tried a few ways but can't get the same compiler as the others in CLion.

Comment: Assuming you use GCC, then all you need to do is add the `-std=c11` option when building your code.

Comment: As for installing and configuring VSCode and GCC, please see [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw).

Comment: "cant get the same compiler" what compiler do they have? What's your OS?

Comment: This is probably the wrong place to look for advice with your problem. There are plenty youtube-tutorials tough. In general: `VS Code` is an editor (a good one). It has no compiler installed with it  and does not provide the same features as `CLion` out of the box. If you want the same features on Windows, `Visual Studio` is probably what you are looking for (yes that is not the same as VS Code). I myself find it way easier to develop C on `Linux`. If you use Windows or ChromeOS you can try [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/setup/environment) or similar.